# Talking to best friend after a little fight

Tags: friends, awkward-situations, friendship

So, my best friend and I haven't been in touch for the past few months; and I realised something was wrong only when she stopped talking - leaving me out of her life.

Now that we've reconciled, and are on good terms - I still don't know what really happened? Who'd know what happened, if she suddenly just stopped talking without any red flags?

I don't know if it's my fault, or something that she just doesn't want to talk about; she didn't really say anything yet.

Considering the fact that she's a little (very, very little) immature and has a loose temper, how do I approach her about this? Should I ask her, or not? 
Of course, it is something that bothers me. Given the fact that she hasn't really said anything about it yet, I'm not sure what to do. Is it just some chapter buried in the past or does it deserve to be explored?

Please help me out here, I'm super confused. I don't even know how to bring it up, if I have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, a person can cut the communication with you because they found something you said or did offensive and instead of talking about that with you, they cut the communication just to be polite.

Another possible reason is that when they said something they only want to share with you and you didn't pay attention (it happens). Now, they think that you are an ignorant person and that it's better to stop talking.

There could be more reasons, but I have listed the most common ones according to my experience.

Now, since you both have reconciled and are now at good terms, I'd say stop thinking about the reason, consider either confronting her or moving on because the more you think about it, longer it will stay in your mind and more likely it will jeopardize your friendship. Look for the subtle hints if she wants you to talk about it (As commented by @SandyC). If yes then talk about it.

Now, if you want to confront her, find the best time when you're both alone and try to let her know that you're sorry and confused about what exactly happened.

> I am sorry if I came across in a rude or inappropriate way back then. I am still confused about what really happened.

You should take whatever she responds in a positive way. If she says that she is over it and doesn't want to talk about that any longer, don't pressure her and move on. If she tells you the reason, see how you can improve yourself.

Comment: How long should I wait for, before asking her? It's just been a few days since the 'reconciliation'

Comment: I'd say let the dust settle, a couple of days more. Talk about it normally. Once you apologize and ask her, she will know that you are open to talk about it and will let you know.

Comment: There is also a possibility that she might or might not expect you to discuss about it. Observe if she is leaving any subtle hints about it.

Comment: @schrodinger_16 I agree with Sandy C.

Comment: As far as I can understand, she's sort of trying to push it under the carpet and not bringing it up, so, I think it's time I do it?

Comment: Yes. As I said, forget what happened and continue with your friendship.

Comment: A J, thank you so much, we talked about it today, and all is great now - back to normal! I think this incident has brought us closer than ever before, and as they say, all that happens is for good! Cheers!

Comment: @schrodinger_16 Cool! Great to know!